# Host a asp.net or jsp website using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to host a asp.net or jsp website using node.js on server side.

Answer (score 4):

## use npm request

This is great for proxying request to other web servers and this is exactly what Wallmart does for its java stuff.

```
req.pipe(request('http://[some site].com')).pipe(resp)
```

But, its not possible to run java code or asp.net code inside node unless there was some script transpiler. That sounds kind of round about.